# From where will hibernate fetch values

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Can someone clarify my doubt.

```
public class MyClass{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

     public String getName() {
          return name + " Hello";
     }
      public static void main() {
             User u = new User();
             u.setName("Yethendra");
      }
}
```

If I try to insert this record into a database using hibernate, what is the value that will be inserted for the `name` column?

Comment: What does that code have to do with Hibernate?

Comment: I want to insert the user object I created in the above code to hibernate

Comment: So what prevented you from using Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=does+hibernate+use+getters+or+properties+directly&oq=does+hibernate+use+getters+or+properties+directly

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you are using `save(user)` It will persist what you have on the name variable.

The only way to modify your variable is calling the `setName()` method.
`getName()` never reassign the name variable.

Comment: What will be used (field or getter) depends on access mode for that particular entity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676689/does-hibernate-always-need-a-setter-when-there-is-a-getter